# Defining missing values in R?

Tags: r, spss

I'm interested in learning more about system missings in R and would be grateful for any advice.

For example, in SPSS this is fairly straightforward and I would usually do the following:

```
*Define missing values using 8 and 9

MISSING VALUES income (8, 9).

*Remove defined missing values

MISSING VALUES income ().
```

Firstly, is it necessary to do this in R, if so how?

Grateful for any advice.

Cheers.

Comment: Maybe read about `?NA`

Comment: is.na(x) <- value

Comment: so something like:

    data2018$income2 <- (is.na(data2018$income) <- 9)